# T4 include Directive broken after installing VS2013 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, include, t4

After updating to **Visual Studio 2013 Update 3**, the following code in a **T4 template** breaks.

```
<#@ include file="../File1.tt" #>
```

It worked as expected in all previous versions of VS.
With this Update, all the variants:

```
<#@ include file="../File1.tt" #>
<#@ include file="..\File1.tt" #>
<#@ include file="..\\File1.tt" #>
```

Fails with the following error:

```
There was an error loading the include file '..\\File1.tt'. The transformation will not    be run. The following Exception was thrown:
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
  at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
  at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
  at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.VisitedFiles.Visit(String fileLocation)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessIncludeDirective(Directive directive, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, VisitedFiles includedFiles) in line: 234 in file: C:\...\mytemplate.tt
```

Any known workaround or fix for this issue?

Comment: I just tried this in Visual Studio 2013 Express (Desktop) Update 3. I couldn't reproduce this. Hopefully this is just an issue with your install. Do you run in a special culture?

Comment: Using ``en-us`` locale for VS in a ``es-es`` OS machine. Reproduced in two machines with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Uninstalling the Update 3 resolves the issue. Moreover, we have a report of the same issue with a en-us VS + en-us OS.

Comment: Me and my colleague got the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root cause found.

When implementing the interface `ITextTemplatingEngineHost` one of the method to implement is:

```
public bool LoadIncludeText(
              string requestFileName, out string content, out string location)
```

In all previous versions before **VS2013 Update 3** returning a valid filename in the `location` parameter as output was not required. In fact, we send `string.Empty`.

Accordingly to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost.loadincludetext(v=vs.110).aspx) the value can be empty if the template is not file-system based. See doc reference:

> **location** *Type: String*
>   A String that contains the location of the
>   acquired text. If the host searches the registry for the location of
>   include files or if the host searches multiple locations by default,
>   the host can return the final path of the include file in this
>   parameter. The host can set the location to **Empty** if the file could
>   not be found **or if the host is not file-system based**.

However with Update 3, something has changed and T4 engine checks and expects the `location` parameter to be a non-empty file path. `String.Empty` value result in the original commented exception.

As a temporal workaround: passing a valid file name to the `location` parameter on method `LoadIncludeText` when implementing `ITextTemplateEngineHost` avoids the exception.

Thanks to [@rubenjmarrufo](https://twitter.com/rubenjmarrufo) in the hunt for the bug.

**Update:** Confirmed bug by Microsoft. It will be fixed on Update 4. Commented workaround is valid.

Comment: We don't have this method implemented in our code. Can you tell if there are other solutions?

Comment: No, to my knowledge @naomi. Can you provide more details about your use case? If it is a different scenario, open a new question.

Comment: In our case it failed on this line <#@ include file="..\..\Utilities\Utilities.ttinclude" #> So, in order to bypass the error we included the text of these include files into the main tt files.

Comment: Update 4 was released today. Do you know if that bug was fixed or not?

Comment: Naomi: Asked the people in charge at MS, they confirmed the fix is included in Update 4.